# How to change specific(that have special value) RecyclerView's imageview show up

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm making a bus application for my graduation project. 
I have two bus info apis, and using `RecyclerView` to show these info.

I want to make hidden imageview to show up when this position(?)'s `RecyclerView` has special tracker value. So I just use

```java
holder.tv_buspointer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

to show up.

I wasn't sure it would work, so I put the tracker value in the last `Arraylist`(that is used in adapter).  I had to scroll to the end of the screen to check the visible imageview. Everything looked find before I scroll to upper side. Some recyclerview's imageview showed up too. When I scroll higher, I could see a lot of showed up imageview that wasn't supposed to be visible.

I think something is wrong with `onBindViewHolder` method in recyclerview.
Could you guys help me with this?

Thank you.

```java
package com.example.absin.firebasebus;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by absin on 2019-05-17.
 */

class station_after {  //노선이 가지고 있는 정류장을 모두 출력하기 위해 만든 클래스
    String stationId; //정류소 아이디
    String mobileNo; //정류소 번호
    String stationName;
    int tracker =0;


    public String getStationId() { return stationId; }
    public String getMobileNo() { return mobileNo; }
    public String getStationName() { return stationName; }

    public int getTracker() { return tracker; }


    public void setStationId(String stationId) { this.stationId = stationId; }
    public void setStationName(String stationName) { this.stationName = stationName; }
    public void setMobileNo(String mobileNo) { this.mobileNo = mobileNo; }

    public void setTracker(int tracker) {this.tracker = tracker; }
}

class station_tracker { //이 클래스의 용도에 대한 자세한 설명은 Station_After_Number의 MySyncTask3 class 바로 위에 작성해두었다.
    String stationId;

    public String getStaionId() { return stationId;}

    public void setStationId(String stationId) {this.stationId= stationId;}
}


public class AdapterSAN extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterSAN.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<station_after> mList;
    private LayoutInflater mInflate;
    private Context mContext;
    View view;

    public AdapterSAN(Context context, ArrayList<station_after> itmes) {
        this.mList = itmes;
        this.mInflate = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mContext = context;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         view = mInflate.inflate(R.layout.san_iten, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    //뷰에 값이 채워질 3개를 여기서 하는 것
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

          holder.tv_stationName.setText(mList.get(position).stationName);



        holder.tv_buspointer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //Click event
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    //ViewHolder
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tv_stationName;
        public ImageView tv_buspointer;


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tv_stationName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_stationname2);
            tv_buspointer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_image);

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView` recycles views from other positions (hence the name).

Be sure your `onBindViewHolder` can handle such case, so ViewHolders that were previously bound to position that met the condition and shown imageView properly hide it when reused for items that don't.

```
if(condition)
    holder.tv_buspointer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else
    holder.tv_buspointer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```